# Upgrading from 10.04 to 12.04.1 stuck at downloading python-qt4

Tags: upgrade

I am a Java programmer and I consider myself a Linux newbie. So I could use a little help here.

I am trying to update my Ubuntu from version 10.04 to 12.04.1 (LTS). The downloading start and runs at around 10MB/s until I am somewhere near 26% and the speed just drops to 0.

I figured I could use the command `do-release-update` so I could see what it was doing. Again the same occurred: the downloading got stuck on 26% at `http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main python-qt4 1386 4.9.1-2ubuntu1`. It says it downloaded 41% of that file/package. It also tries another wget on the same file every X seconds.

Help?

Comment: Try changing repository servers in Software Sources to the main server

Comment: get them here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors